# Find Logic from String using Regex

Tags: php, regex

i want to get logic from string that what from input string. For example:
Input:

```
pageType == "static" OR pageType == "item" AND pageRef == "index"
```

How to i get logic like:

```
0 => pageType == "static"
1 => pageType == "item"
2 => pageRef == "index"
```

The logic clause must be complete based on what is entered.

I place like this:

```
$input = 'pageType == "static" OR pageType == "item" AND pageRef == "index"';
preg_match_all('/(.+)(?!AND|OR)(.+)/s', $input, $loX);
var_dump($loX);
```

but the array just show:

```
0 => pageType == "static" OR pageType == "item" AND pageRef == "index"
1 => pageType == "static" OR pageType == "item" AND pageRef == "index
2 => "
```

Please help me, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make use of the `\G` anchor and a capture group:

```
\G(\w+\h*==\h*"[^"]*")(?:\h+(?:OR|AND)\h+|$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\G` Get continuous matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match from the start of the string
- `(\w+\h*==\h*"[^"]*")` Match 1+ word characters `==` and the value between double quotes
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\h+(?:OR|AND)\h+` Match either OR or AND between spaces
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FFHYt4/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/1UDSu)

```
$re = '/\G(\w+\h*==\h*"[^"]*")(?:\h+(?:OR|AND)\h+|$)/';
$str = 'pageType == "static" OR pageType == "item" AND pageRef == "index"';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => pageType == "static"
    [1] => pageType == "item"
    [2] => pageRef == "index"
)
```

---

Another option to [get the results](https://3v4l.org/5ppKC) is to split on the AND or OR surrounded by spaces:

```
$result = preg_split('/\h+(?:OR|AND)\h+/', $str);
```

Comment: I try first, wait!

Comment: @FSodic Did it work out?

Comment: no, still same as my previous

Comment: but, i'll try the another option

Comment: @FSodic There is example code for both options, for which string does the first one not work?

Comment: `$result = preg_split('/\h+(?:OR|AND)\h+/', $str);` i use this, and it work thanks